# Deuteronomy 6:7 and 8:10 - Why are the words pronounced "Milra"?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

I'm relaying this question from my shul's chazzan to me, who is a Torah reader. I'm stumped...

Deuteronomy 8:10:

> **וְאָכַלְתָּ֖** וְשָׂבָ֑עְתָּ **וּבֵֽרַכְתָּ֙** אֶת־יְהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֔יךָ
>   עַל־הָאָ֥רֶץ הַטֹּבָ֖ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר נָֽתַן־לָֽךְ

As you can see from the position of the trope notes, the 2 bolded words are pronounced on the final syllable - *milra*. My chazzan asks why is this so, when these two words are really accented on the 2nd syllable when spoken in conversational Hebrew.

E.g. you say, "a-CHAL-ta" and "Be-RACH-ta".

Another example is Deuteronomy 6:7:

וְשִׁנַּנְתָּ֣ם לְבָנֶ֔יךָ **וְדִבַּרְתָּ֖** בָּ֑ם בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ֤ בְּבֵיתֶ֙ךָ֙ וּבְלֶכְתְּךָ֣ בַדֶּ֔רֶךְ וּֽבְשָׁכְבְּךָ֖ וּבְקוּמֶֽךָ

Is the conversational pronunciation incorrect, or is there a different ruling to the accent when there a vav hahipuch (vav that converts the verb tense?)

(The above is one of many examples, where we see this. So, your answer need not focus on just this example. BTW, in the 2nd example, the chazzan stated that since בָּ֑ם is a single syllable verb, the accent on the previous word should have a nasog achor, and move back 1 syllable, which it doesn't, here. )

Comment: ודברת is on a pausal trop (Tipcha) so no Nasog Achor. If you add a Nasog Achor you might have to repeat Keriat Shema, see below.

Comment: From memory this is in order to make it a tzivui rather than just a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it has to do with the "Vav HaHippukh" ([waw-consecutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waw-consecutive)). Were those words pronounced Mil'eil, they would be in past tense (eg. Lev 10:19 , Hos 12:11) instead of the future tense. Thus, changing the accent is actually a correctable reading mistake.

Comment: Is it possible to say that the point is that uverachta is not an hefsek? (I am Am hoorets gomur) and mil'eil is for end of piska

Comment: @kouty Being on a Hefsek can make even the future tense version move back to the standard Mil'eil (see [Mikhlol](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C_(%D7%A8%D7%93%22%D7%A7)#.D7.90.D7.91.D7.9F_.D7.91.27)). There are other exceptions too (like roots that end in ה in Kal (eg. ועשית), or Nasog Achor (eg. Deu 14:26)). I'm not sure what you mean by "the point".